# Расставить понятия от частного к общему

Tags: общие-вопросы

личность, человек, мировоззрение, нравственный идеал, направленность, сознание

Comment: А как Вы предлагаете расставить?

Comment: направленность- сознание - личность - нравственный идеал - мировоззрение - человек

Answer (score 1):

Предлагается такое решение (от частного к общему):
нравственный идеал – направленность –  мировоззрение – сознание – личность – человек.

Для ответа на этот вопрос желательно использовать толковый словарь, тогда становится ясным переход от общего понятия к частному.

1. Идеал - тот, кто является совершенным воплощением чего-л.
2. Направленность - целенаправленная сосредоточенность на чём-л. мыслей, интересов.
3. Мировоззрение  - совокупность принципов, взглядов и убеждений, определяющих отношение  человека к действительности
4. Сознание   - только ментальный план: понимание,  осознание человеком окружающей действительности.
5. Личность - совокупность свойств, присущих данному человеку, составляющих его индивидуальность (ментальность, эмоции, поведение и др.)
6. Человек (физический, эмоциональный, поведенческий и  и ментальный план как совокупность)

Думаю, что эти понятия можно связать по принципу перехода от максимально сложной системы (человек)  к его нравственному идеалу путем последовательного исключения различных его планов (физического, поведенческого и т.д), а также сужения предмета его ментальной деятельности: сознание - мировоззрение - направленность - идеал.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, здесь нужно по парам, потому что человек-сознание-идеал - понятия разные

личность- человек(личность-конкретный человек)

мировоззрение- сознание(мировоззрение-форма сознания)

нравственный идеал- направленность(идеал-форма направленности)